# php shell_exec regular expression PCRE/POSIX

Tags: php, regex, posix, pcre, shell-exec

I have a problem with my php-script when I call `shell_exec` and pass a *regular expression*.

**PHP code :**

```
shell_exec("sh myscript.sh 'FOO\s*ONE'");
```

**myscript.sh :**

```
result=$(grep -c "${1}"  myLongFile.txt)
echo ${result}
```

Like this, it returns `0` but if il call directly with cmd `grep -c "FOO\s*ONE"  myLongFile.txt` it returns `23`.

And if i replace in my php script `\s` by the class `[[:space:]]` it's working, but I have to use `\s`

I tried many solutions but failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all,

I find the solution, i just add option -P for grep in my script like this :

```
result=$(grep -P -c "${1}"  myLongFile.txt)
```

Now, i can use **\s**

> -P, --perl-regexp
>           Interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the `\` character with an other `\`, so it becomes:

```
 shell_exec("sh myscript.sh 'FOO\\s*ONE'");
```

Comment: thank u, bu it doesn't work... i have already test this solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the backslash:

```
shell_exec("sh myscript.sh 'FOO\\s*ONE'");
```

Comment: thank u, bu it doesn't work... i have already test this solution

Comment: `grep` doesn't normally use PCRE. Maybe you have your `$PATH` set up to find a version of `grep` that's actually `pcregrep`? But the PHP script is being run in a process with different `$PATH`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the escaping, but simply because `grep` is POSIX based; this is why you should use `[[:space:]]` instead of `\s`. Some versions of `grep` support PCRE syntax using the `-P` option, but using POSIX is more portable.

Also, if you want to pass a variable from PHP to a shell script it's advisable to use `escapeshellarg()`:

```
$re = 'FOO[[:space:]]*ONE';
shell_exec(sprintf("sh myscript.sh %s", escapeshellarg($re)));
```

It should be mentioned that `escapeshellarg()` doesn't work consistently between Windows and Linux (and even between shells); in some cases you need to apply `addcslashes()`.